# Python tkinter scroll frame, expand LabelFrame in canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, expand

Good day. I have a problem with scroll frame. I use ready-made solution (http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-autoscrollbar.htm)

But I do not know how to expand the LabelFrame ("kontakty") by the window? Excuse my English

```
#prevzato z http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-autoscrollbar.htm

from Tkinter import *

class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
    # a scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.  only
    # works if you use the grid geometry manager.
def set(self, lo, hi):
    if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
        # grid_remove is currently missing from Tkinter!
        self.tk.call("grid", "remove", self)
    else:
        self.grid()
    Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)
def pack(self, **kw):
    raise TclError, "cannot use pack with this widget"
def place(self, **kw):
    raise TclError, "cannot use place with this widget"

root = Tk()


master = Frame(root)
master.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)


vscrollbar = AutoScrollbar(master)
vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
hscrollbar = AutoScrollbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
hscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)

master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)



canvas = Canvas(master,
            yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set,
            xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set, bg = "red", width = 200, height = 400)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
hscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

# make the canvas expandable
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#
# create canvas contents

kontakty = LabelFrame(canvas, width = 600, height =400, text = "Skupina" )
kontakty.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

kontakty.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
kontakty.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)



canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=NW, window=kontakty)

kontakty.update_idletasks()

canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

windows that are created as canvas objects must be told how wide to be if you want them to be other than their natural size.

The most common way to do this is to bind to the canvas's `<Configure>` event which will get called each time the size of the canvas changes (such as when it is first drawn, or when the user resizes the window). You can then query for the size of the canvas and then iterate over all the embedded widgets and set their size to the width of the canvas (minus any borders or margins you want, obviously).